# Implications of pistons on farmland in 19W37A

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

As stated in [Minecraft Snapshot 19W37A change notes](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-19w37a):

> Blocks that can be manually placed on farmland can now also be pushed onto it by a piston without destroying the farmland

What are the implications of this simple change?

Mainly, I'm interested in the applications of automated farming. 
For example, does this mean that I can line up a set of pistons behind my crops to destroy them all automatically now? Obviously I would still need to replant them afterwards.

Or instead, does this just mean that if I have one crop, I can transfer it to an empty farmland plot with a piston?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy(/harvest) crops by extending a piston into it now, yes.

Some other blocks than piston head also work, as demonstrated by this farm design: